# MonoTouch and NUnitLite: what is the "Host" setting for?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.ios, nunit, touch.unit

I'm using NUnitLite quite a lot but have always been wondering what the host settings are about in the options menu. The options aren't explained in the documentation here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Unit_Testing

Can somebody shed some light on this feature that might maybe change my life forever, if only I knew about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for test automation (e.g. from build bots) where the test output results, normally sent to the console, are sent to a TCP socket server.

Blogs entries on the subjet:

- [Touch.Unit Automation](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/touch-unit-automation/)
- [Touch.Unit Automation Revisited](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/touch-unit-automation-revisited/)

A simple server is [available](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/tree/master/Touch.Server) in touch.unit github repository.